# Invalid arrarify value with web3 and react js

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I am using web3 with react js and I'm trying to burn tokens from address, but it doesn't work throwing an error regarding an arrarify value although I don't have any array in my code since I'm passing the amount input value as a string. Based on the same syntax I implemented the mint function and it works perfectly but when I change from mint to burn, it doesn't work.For some reason the input value of amount is taken as hex value instead of string. Can someone please tell me what exactly is this error and why is it thrown every time I try to burn tokens from address?
This is my code for the view:

```html
class Token extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      beneficiary: '',
      amount: '0',
      input: '',
      mint_state: true,
      burn_state: false,
      transfer: false,
      transfer_from: false,
      send: false
    };

  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.mint_state) {
      return (
        <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          // this.state.amount = (this.input.value * 10 ** 18).toString()
          this.props.mintTokens(this.state.beneficiary, this.state.amount)

        }}>

          <div className="dropdown input-group-append">
            <button className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

              &nbsp;&nbsp;MINT
            </button>
            <div className="dropdown-menu backgrd-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: true })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: false })
                this.setState({ transfer: false })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: false })
              }}>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;BURN
              </button>
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: true })
                this.setState({ transfer: false })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: false })
              }}>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;SEND
              </button>
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: false })
                this.setState({ transfer: true })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: false })
              }}>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;TRANSFER
              </button>
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: false })
                this.setState({ transfer: false })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: true })
              }}>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;TRANSFER FROM
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="full-width">
            <InputGroup size="sm" type="number" className="mb-3" value={this.state.beneficiary} onChange={(event) => {
              this.setState({ beneficiary: event.target.value })
            }} ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
              <InputGroup.Prepend >
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">To</InputGroup.Text>

              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
            </InputGroup>

            <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3" value={this.state.amount} onChange={(event) => {
              this.setState({ amount: event.target.value * 10 ** 18 })
            }} ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Amount</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
            </InputGroup>
            <div className="submit-button">
              <div className="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" >Mint</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )
    }else if (this.state.burn_state) {
      return (
        <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          this.props.burnTokens(this.state.beneficiary, this.state.amount)
        }}>

          <div className="dropdown input-group-append">
            <button className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

              &nbsp;&nbsp;BURN
            </button>
            <div className="dropdown-menu backgrd-dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: true })
                this.setState({ send: false })
                this.setState({ transfer: false })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: false })
              }}>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;MINT
              </button>
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: true })
                this.setState({ transfer: false })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: false })
              }}>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;SEND
              </button>
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: false })
                this.setState({ transfer: true })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: false })
              }}>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;TRANSFER
              </button>
              <button className="dropdown-item icon-dropdown" type="button" onClick={(event) => {
                this.setState({ burn_state: false })
                this.setState({ mint_state: false })
                this.setState({ send: false })
                this.setState({ transfer: false })
                this.setState({ transfer_from: true })
              }}>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;TRANSFER FROM
              </button>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div className="full-width">
            <InputGroup size="sm" type="number" className="mb-3" value={this.state.beneficiary} onChange={(event) => {
              this.setState({ beneficiary: event.target.value })
            }} ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
              <InputGroup.Prepend >
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">To</InputGroup.Text>

              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
            </InputGroup>

            <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3" value={this.state.amount} onChange={(event) => {
              this.setState({ amount: event.target.value * 10 ** 18 })
            }} ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Amount</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
            </InputGroup>
            <div className="submit-button">
              <div className="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" >Burn</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )
    }
  }
}
export default Token;
```

and this is the contract function called in **app.js**:

```
  burnTokens = (beneficiary,amount) => {
      this.setState({ loading: true })
      this.state.token.methods.burn(beneficiary,amount.toString()).send({ from:this.state.account})
      .once('confirmation', (confirmation,info) => {
        this.loadBlockchainData()
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      })
        .on("error", (error) => {
          this.setState({ loading: true })
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
```